# Почему rgb triplet не конвертируется в название?

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь:

```
mycolor = "240,240,240"
mycolor = webcolors.rgb_to_name((mycolor))
```

Но ничего не выходит.

В чем может заключаться причина?

Comment: С чего вы взяли что ничего не выходит?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

функция `webcolors.rgb_to_name()` ожидает на вход **кортеж с тремя целыми значениями**, а вы подаете ей на вход **строку**.

Попробуйте так:

```
mycolor = (240,240,240)
mycolor = webcolors.rgb_to_name(mycolor)
```

---

Если цвет у вас изначально задан как **строка**, тогда его можно распарсить:

```
from ast import literal_eval

mycolor = "240,240,240"

if isinstance(mycolor, str):
    mycolor = literal_eval(mycolor)

mycolor = webcolors.rgb_to_name(mycolor)
```

Comment: 1-м вариантом уже пробовал - не помогло,. Благодарю за помощь